# shape=record ignored by dot2texi

Tags: dot2tex, dot2texi

I'm trying to draw record nodes with `dot2texi`, but it seems to ignore the `shape=record` attribute.  Here's my LaTeX code:

```
% tmp.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{dot2tex}
  graph G {
     n[label="{a|b}", shape=record];
  }
\end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

I typeset this with `pdflatex --shell-escape tmp.tex` and the node comes out as an ellipse, the | symbol replaced by an em dash.

[image]

I expected a rectangle separated into two boxes labeled a and b, or if I somehow have to escape the |, at least a rectangular node.

Moreover, the `tmp-dot2tex-fig1.dot` file that `dot2texi` creates along the way won't typeset properly either, but in a different way: when I do `dot2tex tmp-dot2tex-fig1.dot > fig1.tex && pdflatex --shell-escape fig1.tex` I get the labels a and b with no borders around it.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong, or are records not supposed to work with `dot2tex(i)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot2tex documentation says that HTML and record labels are **not** supported:

http://dot2tex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage_guide.html#preprocessing-graphs